# Cannot add custom attributes in OpenLDAP

Tags: ldap, openldap

I'd like to add custom attributes in OpenLDAP but I maybe do not understand the concept. What I've done was:

I created the custom.schema

```
attributetype ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.4203.666.100.122
        NAME ( 'dateOfBirth' )
        SUP name
        )

attributetype ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.4203.666.100.123
        NAME ( 'IPPhone' )
        SUP name
        )

objectclass     ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.4203.666.100.1
    NAME 'customAttributes'
        DESC 'Custom attributes class'
    )
```

I added to slapd.conf

```
include         /usr/local/etc/openldap/schema/custom.schema
```

And now I'd like to assign this object class to every uid I have in the current database. So I dumped the db, added objectclass atribute to some uid, and while importing the LDIF, ldap says:

```
65) invalid structural object class chain (inetOrgPerson/customAttributes)
```

The LDIF entry is like this:

```
dn: dc=sss,dc=com
objectClass: top
objectClass: dcObject
objectClass: organization
o: sss.com
dc: sss
structuralObjectClass: organization

dn: ou=People,dc=sss,dc=com
objectClass: organizationalUnit
ou: People
structuralObjectClass: organizationalUnit


dn: uid=zzz,ou=People,dc=sss,dc=com
objectClass: posixAccount
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: person
objectClass: customAttributes
structuralObjectClass: inetOrgPerson
...
```

Could you please navigate me how can I add those custom attributes ?

Comment: Check to ensure you do not have two structural object classes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears from the *invalid structural object class chain* error that there is a violation of the STRUCTURAL objectClass rule. Without declaration to the contrary your customAttributes objectClass is being seen as a STRUCTURAL objectClass which it can't be and still work along with inetOrgPerson. I would recommend try changing your schema to something along the lines of the following:

```
objectclass     ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.4203.666.100.1
    NAME 'customAttributes'
    AUXILIARY
    DESC 'Custom attributes class'
    MAY (dateofBirth $ IPPhone)
)
```

For a further explanation I'd read over common causes of errors in the [LDAP Guide](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books//network_administration_guides/ldap_administration/appendix-common-errors_Common_causes_of_LDAP_errors.html). Beyond that a cursory look of the schema you are trying to create could use some more thought into organization. Usually advisable to have objectClass entities under one tree and attributeType entities under another to avoid confusion and collision.

Comment: I found out it earlier, but however thanks!

Answer (score 1):

your new objectclass needs to reference the new attributes.  Usually done as a MAY clause

```
objectclass     ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.4203.666.100.1
    NAME 'customAttributes'
    DESC 'Custom attributes class'
    MAY (dateofBirth $ IPPhone)
)
```

There may be other requirements.  The [OpenLDAP admin guide](http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/index.html) is the best place to start.  here is the [Class info](http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/schema.html#Object%20Class%20Specification)

Comment: This is not the problem. It seems that the schema is somehow not recognized at all :(

Answer (score 0):

Did you modify the schema according to the posts above? And, in addition, ìs the .schema file readable and has the correct permissions?

Does the syslog (or log file of the slapd) give any errors when restarting?